# Perl script to process a text file

Tags: perl, file-handling, text-processing

I have a file of the following format **ideally**:

```
Status_ArsFlag = ""
Status_NodeAlias = ""
OID1 = ".1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.17.19.2.2.1"
1 = "NNMi"
2 = "ASB"
3 = "456"
RawCaptureTimeStamp = 1450091580


Status_Identifier = ""
Status_NodeAlias = ""
OID1 = ".1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.17.19.2.2.1"
1 = "NNMi"
2 = "ASB"
3 = "456"
RawCaptureTimeStamp = 1450091580


Status_Node = ""
Status_NodeAlias = ""
OID1 = ".1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.17.19.2.2.1"
1 = "NNMi"
2 = "ASB"
3 = "456"
RawCaptureTimeStamp = 1450091580
```

Where each data set ideally begins with "**Status_**" line and ends with "**RawCaptureTimeStamp**" separated by 2 new lines.

Now the problem is in non ideal cases, where the file can look like below:

```
1 = "NNMi"
2 = "ASB"
3 = "456"
RawCaptureTimeStamp = 1450091580


Status_ArsFlag = ""
Status_NodeAlias = ""
OID1 = ".1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.17.19.2.2.1"
1 = "NNMi"
2 = "ASB"
3 = "456"
RawCaptureTimeStamp = 1450091580


Status_ArsFlag = ""
Status_NodeAlias = ""
OID1 = ".1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.17.19.2.2.1"
1 = "NNMi"
```

As seen above the first and last data set are invalid. I need a logic in which i can remove these unwanted data sets from the original file and re-save it.
I have tried several things in PERL, but have failed spectacularly. Please help.
Code that i am using to read the file and check if the file begins with status and if not read till it reaches rawcapturetimestamp.

```
while( my $line = <$cap_1>){
    if($. == 1 && $line !~ /^Status/){ #check if first line doesn't begin with status
            while($line = <$cap_1>){#if not read till the occurence of RawCaptureTimeStamp
            if($line =~/^RawCaptureTimeStamp/){
                $. = $.+1;
                last;
            }
        }
        $line = <$cap_1>; 
        if (eof()){ #After reading till raw capture timestamp, check for EOF
            last;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So, blank lines always delimit the blocks?  Read the file in paragraph mode (set `$/ = "\n\n";`, for example), then analyze each paragraph.

Comment: You said you've tried several things. Where's that code?

Comment: I have written a solution for you because it interested me and took me into corners of Perl that I neded to revise. But [**Matt Jacob**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34270575/perl-script-to-process-a-text-file#comment56285293_34270575) is right—Stack Overflow is here to offer a library of solutions to commonly-encountered problems. It is ***not*** a place to go when you would rather put your feet up than do some work.

Comment: Sorry for not putting up the code that i used, i have done the part to read the file to covert it to a CSV file but only for the ideal case. I have edited my answer, to show the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just read the file in paragraph mode (setting `$/` to `""` and not `"\n\n"` as
[**Jonathan Leffler** commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34270575/perl-script-to-process-a-text-file#comment56282641_34270575) on your question)
and check each paragraph for conformance

The three newlines must be replaced at the end of each block, as PerlIO normalises them to two in this mode

It looks like the problem is that the data may be truncated at either end, so I've required ten digits for the timestamp, which covers dates from 2001 to 2286

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

local $/ = ''; # Separate reads by one or more blank lines

while ( <> ) {

    next unless /^Status.+\nStatus/ and /^RawCaptureTimeStamp = \d{10}/m;
    s/\s*\z/\n\n\n/;

    print;
}
```

**output** (using your faulty example data set)

```
Status_ArsFlag = ""
Status_NodeAlias = ""
OID1 = ".1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.17.19.2.2.1"
1 = "NNMi"
2 = "ASB"
3 = "456"
RawCaptureTimeStamp = 1450091580
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Even the date time consideration is a +

Answer (score 0):

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

$_ = q();
$_ = <> until /^Status_/; # Skip the invalid beginning;

my $block = $_;

while (<>) {
    if (/^RawCaptureTimeStamp/) {  # End of block: print it, start gathering a new one.
        print $block, $_;
        $block = q();

    } else {                       # Inside of a block.
        $block .= $_;
    }
}
```

The last block won't be printed if it doesn't end properly.

Comment: This will pass through any block that starts with the *second `Status_` line. You are also assuming that the errors are always in the first and last blocks, which I agree is likely, but not confirmed

Comment: Also, given that it looks like the data is a snapshot of a stream and so may start and end anywhere within a block, you should check that `RawCaptureTimeStamp` is followed by a sensible *value*

Answer (score 0):

This works, I believe:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

$/ = "\n\n";

while (<>)
{
    s/^\s+//;
    s/\s+$//;
    print "\n[[", $_, "]]\n"
        if (m/^Status_\w+ .*Status_\w+ /ms && m/^RawCaptureTimeStamp /m);
}
```

Setting `$/` reads up to a double newline (or EOF), effectively reading a paragraph at a time.  The `if` condition looks for two `Status_` elements and a `RawCaptureTimeStamp`; you can refine those conditions as you need, making them more stringent.  The `s` modifier allows the `.*` to match embedded newlines; the `m` modifier is for multiline mode.  For example, this would be OK with the `RawCaptureTimeStamp` followed by other lines.

Sample data, copied from the question:

```
Status_ArsFlag = ""
Status_NodeAlias = ""
OID1 = ".1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.17.19.2.2.1"
1 = "NNMi"
2 = "ASB"
3 = "456"
RawCaptureTimeStamp = 1450091580


Status_Identifier = ""
Status_NodeAlias = ""
OID1 = ".1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.17.19.2.2.1"
1 = "NNMi"
2 = "ASB"
3 = "456"
RawCaptureTimeStamp = 1450091580


Status_Node = ""
Status_NodeAlias = ""
OID1 = ".1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.17.19.2.2.1"
1 = "NNMi"
2 = "ASB"
3 = "456"
RawCaptureTimeStamp = 1450091580


1 = "NNMi"
2 = "ASB"
3 = "456"
RawCaptureTimeStamp = 1450091580


Status_ArsFlag = ""
Status_NodeAlias = ""
OID1 = ".1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.17.19.2.2.1"
1 = "NNMi"
2 = "ASB"
3 = "456"
RawCaptureTimeStamp = 1450091580


Status_ArsFlag = ""
Status_NodeAlias = ""
OID1 = ".1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.17.19.2.2.1"
1 = "NNMi"
```

Sample output:

```
[[Status_ArsFlag = ""
Status_NodeAlias = ""
OID1 = ".1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.17.19.2.2.1"
1 = "NNMi"
2 = "ASB"
3 = "456"
RawCaptureTimeStamp = 1450091580]]

[[Status_Identifier = ""
Status_NodeAlias = ""
OID1 = ".1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.17.19.2.2.1"
1 = "NNMi"
2 = "ASB"
3 = "456"
RawCaptureTimeStamp = 1450091580]]

[[Status_Node = ""
Status_NodeAlias = ""
OID1 = ".1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.17.19.2.2.1"
1 = "NNMi"
2 = "ASB"
3 = "456"
RawCaptureTimeStamp = 1450091580]]

[[Status_ArsFlag = ""
Status_NodeAlias = ""
OID1 = ".1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.17.19.2.2.1"
1 = "NNMi"
2 = "ASB"
3 = "456"
RawCaptureTimeStamp = 1450091580]]
```

Comment: `$/ = "\n\n"` is *not* the way to set PerlIO to paragraph mode. It's also a little shabby to leave the square brackets in what is supposed to be a demo of your solution

Comment: The problem, which is exemplified here, is that `$/ = "\n\n"` may cause records containing just two newlines to be returned, or (as it seems you discovered) records that *start* with a newline. All of that is handled for you with `$/ = ""`

Answer (score 0):

Use `Perl` **paragraph mode**, as described [here](http://learn.perl.org/faq/perlfaq5.html#How-can-I-read-in-a-file-by-paragraphs)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

local $/ = "";

while (my $para = <DATA>) {
    print $para if ($para =~ /^Status_.*RawCaptureTimeStamp/s);
}

__DATA__
1 = "NNMi"
2 = "ASB"
3 = "456"
RawCaptureTimeStamp = 1450091580


Status_ArsFlag = ""
Status_NodeAlias = ""
OID1 = ".1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.17.19.2.2.1"
1 = "NNMi"
2 = "ASB"
3 = "456"
RawCaptureTimeStamp = 1450091580


Status_ArsFlag = ""
Status_NodeAlias = ""
OID1 = ".1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.17.19.2.2.1"
1 = "NNMi"
```

Comment: This doesn't account for the possibility that the data is missing up to the *second* `Status_` line. It will also pass through paragraphs that end right after `RawCaptureTimeStamp` and don't have a value. It will also reduce the number of intervening blank lines from two to one. You should also prefer `use warnings 'all'` to `-w` on the command line or shebang line

Comment: Thanks,  never to late to improve

Comment: As @Borodin said, i have the same observation to make, however interesting method that i was not aware of. Probably for something else in the future